# How to map a unique id (counting from 0) to items in sublists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, uniqueidentifier

Let's say I have

```
a = [['a1', 'b1'], ['a1', 'b2'], ['a2', 'b1'], ['a2', 'b4']]
```

As a result I want

```
a = [[0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 4]]
```

Give an id to the first item of every sub-list (i.e `a[:][0]`) and then continue with the second item of every sub-list (i.e `a[:][1]`)

I've tried:

```
>>> aa=[[] for cells in range(len(a))]
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        aa[i].append(id(a[i][j]))
```

result:

```
>>> aa
[[34378168, 51409056], [34378168, 51507304], [34301464, 51409056], [34301464, 51467576]]
```

Which is "close" but I want the id to start from `0` and go on.

I know what `id()` returns and I don't need that.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted. The OP has input, expected output, a reasonably clear description of what is needed, and an attempt at solving it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't downvote it, but I still don't get what the OP wants.

Comment: @miindlek: they want to produce a unique number per string value. `a1` is assigned 0, `a2` is 1. That's all the first column values assigned. Then the count continues for the unique 2nd column values: `b1` gets 2, `b2` gets 3, `b4` gets 4. If there were more unique values, more numbers are assigned.

Comment: @miindlek: so `[['foo', 'bar'], ['spam', 'ham'], ['foo', 'baz'], ['spam', 'bar']]` would produce `[[0, 2], [1, 3], [0, 4], [1, 2]]`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, I get it. Thanks.

Comment: New here @ MartijnPieters ,you've been very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count); transpose the sublists with the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) first, transpose back again after assigning numbers:

```
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(lambda c=count(): next(c))

aa = zip(*((counts[cell] for cell in col) for col in zip(*a)))
```

The `defaultdict()` stores a new `count()` value each time a key has not yet been seen, producing a unique counter per string.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a=[['a1', 'b1'], ['a1', 'b2'], ['a2', 'b1'], ['a2', 'b4']]
>>> counts = defaultdict(lambda c=count(): next(c))
>>> zip(*((counts[cell] for cell in col) for col in zip(*a)))
[(0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 4)]
```